# Opening an unknown file type in Android (6.0)

Tags: android, android-intent

Instead of telling a user that they cannot open their file b/c *"there are no supported apps"* (ie Samsung) or something, I wan't to let them choose an app, like **Asus** (KitKat) does with their **File Manager**. Opening a file named *test.noapp* gives the following prompt

[image]

Choosing *Text* then gives a list of text-processing apps

[image]

**Do I have to roll my own *"Open as"* category list, or is there something in the API (level 23) that I can leverage?**

---

The following code is used to open files

```
Intent viewFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);

Android.Net.Uri uriFile = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(selectedAttachmentDetails.File);
string mimeType = GetAttachmentFileTypeMimeString(selectedAttachmentDetails.File.Name);

viewFileIntent.SetDataAndType(uriFile, mimeType);

THIS.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(viewFileIntent, "Complete action using"), 0);

private string GetAttachmentFileTypeMimeString(string attachmentFileName)
{
    string ext = Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(attachmentFileName);
    Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap map = Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.Singleton;

    string mimeType = map.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);    

    return mimeType == null ? "*/*" : mimeType;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why they are asking if it's a `text`, `audio`, `video` etc. is to set the verbose `mime` and let the android OS handle it.

With that in mind you can *guess* the mime and set it. Other than that there is also [guessContentTypeFromStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream(java.io.InputStream))

It's from the class [MimeTypeMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html).

Comment: This is how I figured to implement it if I was to write it myself, I just like leveraging the API whenever possible.

Comment: I'm using the `MimeTypeMap` to discern type. If it returns *null*, then I want the user to decide, not guess for them (`"*/*"` gives too big of a list, so wan't to break it up into categories).

Comment: @SamusArin Yes, you can show a dialog and narrow it down to `text/*`, `audio/*` etc.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't want to write this dialog if there is something already built-in. It's just more code to write and maintain and all that jazz.

Answer (score 0):

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="OpenAsDialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">  
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>  
</style>
```

**OpenAsDialog.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/open_as_dialog_root"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#C0C0C0">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/open_as_dialog_tv_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom ="0.5dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor ="#808080"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/open_as_dialog_tv_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom ="0.5dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Image"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor ="#808080"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/open_as_dialog_tv_audio"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom ="0.5dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Audio"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor ="#808080"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/open_as_dialog_tv_video"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Video"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor ="#808080"/>      
</LinearLayout>
```

**DialogFragment**

```
public class OpenAsDialog : DialogFragment
{
    public static OpenAsDialog NewInstance()
    {
        OpenAsDialog dialogFragment = new OpenAsDialog();            

        return dialogFragment;
    }

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetStyle(DialogFragmentStyle.Normal, Resource.Style.OpenAsDialog);            
    }        

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View messageView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.OpenAsDialog, container, false);            

        return messageView;
    }

    public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Dialog.SetTitle("Open as");
    }        
}
```

**Usage**

```
private void ShowOpenAsDialog()
{
    OpenAsDialog openAsDialog = OpenAsDialog.NewInstance();
    openAsDialog.Show(THIS.FragmentManager, "open_as_dialog");
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html